# Apache OpenSSL 4620:error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error

Tags: apache, openssl

I'm trying to get SSL to work on a bare-bones WAPP (Windows/Apache/PHP/PostgreSQL) custom stack I'm putting together.

I've followed the directions of the following page...

http://www.tehuber.com/article.php?story=20110315153800545

...up until the line specified in 3.D...

> openssl req -new -out server.csr

The Windows command prompt spits the following out...

> C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\OpenSSL x64\bin>openssl req -new
>
> 4620:error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output
> error:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:169:fopen('C:\ 4620:error:2006D002:BIO
> routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:174:
> 4620:error:0E078002:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:system
> lib:.\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:199:

Everything else works fine and the openssl.cnf is untouched from the Apache installer and has no BOM and is UTF8.

---

Should I get SSL working a different way or is this an error someone knows how to help me blow through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it! In the OpenSSL bin directory in the Windows command prompt at...

> C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\OpenSSL x64\bin

I entered the following...

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\OpenSSL x64\bin\openssl.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

@John is right. Another permanent solution: Go to system environment and set the system variable "OPEN_SSL_CONF" to "C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\OpenSSL x64\bin\openssl.cfg" then click apply the changes und restart your terminal if you use it.